# trigger to Preventing the users to create Duplicate Accounts im getting Variable does not exist: Name error

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, duplicate-management

```
trigger AccountDuplicateTrigger on Account (before insert)
{
 for(Account a:Trigger.new)
 {
 List<Account> acc=[Select id from Account where Name='a.Name' and Rating='a.Rating'];
 if(acc.size()>0)
 {
 acc.Name.addError('You Cannot Create the Duplicate Account');
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: This looks like a good use case for Salesforce native duplicate management, not a trigger. I would recommend you invest some time in Trailhead modules like [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk). The logic of this trigger is incorrect in a number of ways, beyond the two major syntax errors - the incorrect Apex binding syntax and use of `addError()` against a record outside `Trigger.new`.

Answer (score 4):

you are using the wrong way of variable binding. Is implemented by means of `:` colon symbol, that should be in your soql:

```
List<Account> acc=[Select id from Account where Name = :a.Name and Rating = :a.Rating];
```

---

by the way, you are using SOQL in a loop, that is very bad and is in opposition to [trigger best-practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

> Best Practice #2: Avoid SOQL Queries or DML statements inside FOR
>   Loops

Answer (score 0):

Adding an error to list is incorrect. so instead add error to the account record which is `a` here in our case `a.addError('your error text here');` and if you want to add it to name field we can also do it by using `a.Name.addError('your error text here');`

Also,

1. Using SOQL query in a loop is not a best practice
2. Name is not a method or property of list so it's incorrect

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. I think this answer would be improved if you went into more detail about _why_ your approach should work, and _why_ the original approach didn't work. The `object.field.addError('text')` approach is valid. When I'm looking at a piece of code and wondering if it'll cause an error, my first stop is usually the official documentation. It's also a good idea to use anonymous apex (from the developer console) to execute the code in question (or similar code) to verify the problem / your solution.

Comment: The above approach is wrong. Adding an error to list is incorrect. so instead add error to the account record which is 'a' here in our case and if you want to add it to name field we can also do it by using a.Name.addError('your error text here');

Comment: Forgot to mention, comments are best thought of as temporary. That additional information should be added to your answer by making an [edit].